# IF statement in Template Toolkit with Perl

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I'm trying to set up a conditional in a .tt2 file using perl. I have an object `page` that i need to check the title against. however I can't seem to get it to work. where am I going wrong here?
I'm just trying to dump out the content at this stage to make sure its working but it just throws a `cannot render template` error message

```
    [% IF page.title eq 'User Api List' %]
        [%
        "<pre>";
        USE dumper(indent = 1);
        dumper.dump(page.title) | html
        "</pre>";
        %]
    [% END %]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I run that code it says:

> ```
> file error - parse error - test.tt line 3: unexpected token (eq)
>   [% IF page.title eq 'User Api List' %]%
> ```

Template Toolkit is not Perl.

The comparison operator for strings is `==` not `eq`

---

You also forgot the `;` after `| html`.

Comment: ah brilliant thanks. that worked! that would explain why i was struggling to find answers online. I was told this was perl :/

Comment: Template Toolkit is written in Perl and often used in combination with a Perl program, but it is its own language.